# Excluding an element with jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to exclude an element from a jquery click event? A simplified version of my issue is this:

CSS

```
.outerbox{
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 background-color:red;
 position:relative;
 }

 .innerbox{
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 background-color:yellow;
 margin:auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="outerbox">
   <div class="innerbox"></div>
 </div>
```

JQUERY

```
 $(".outerbox").not(".innerbox").click(function() {
   alert( "Red has been clicked, but not the yellow area" );
 });
```

My not selector does not work though. I've tried $(".outerbox:not('.innerbox')") too, to no effect. Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can't stop the element from *having* a click event, but you can capture that click event and stop it from propagating through the DOM.  So you would have your outer click event handler as normal:

```
$(".outerbox").click(function() {
  alert( "Red has been clicked, but not the yellow area" );
});
```

And also add a click handler for the "inner" element which does nothing more than cancel the event:

```
$(".innerbox").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xg5z37ag/)

Comment: Unless you are gone do anything with the click it kinda feels unessesary to use a click for innerbox @JohnG

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `target` attribute form the event raised:

```
$(".outerbox").on('click', function(event) {
   var trg = $(event.target);
   if (trg.hasClass('innerbox')) {
      // Inner was clicked
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your JS code with this::

```
$(".outerbox").click(function(event) {
    if($(event.target).attr('class') == 'outerbox')
        alert( "Red has been clicked, but not the yellow area" );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are arent gone do anything with the `innerbox` click I would go with checking the target.

[demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rchcpfjx/1/)

```
$(".outerbox").on('click', function(e) {
   if (e.target.classList.contains('innerbox')) {
        return false;
   }

   // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all about event bubbling, not a jQuery selector issue.

The click event has an [`e.eventPhase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase) property, which indicates which phase of the event flow is currently being evaluated.

`e.eventPhase` takes the value:

- Event.NONE: 0
- Event.CAPTURING_PHASE: 1
- Event.AT_TARGET: 2
- Event.BUBBLING_PHASE: 3

In the event handler, on clicking the red square you should see `e.eventPhase == 2`, and on clicking the yellow square you should see `e.eventPhase == 3`.

So, either of the following will give the desired effect :

```
$(".outerbox").click(function(e) {
    if(e.eventPhase !== Event.BUBBLING_PHASE) {
        // here, clicks on any of the target's child elements are excluded.
        alert( "Red has been clicked, but not the yellow area");
    }
});
```

or

```
$(".outerbox").click(function(e) {
    if(e.eventPhase === Event.AT_TARGET) {
        // here, clicks on any of the target's child elements are excluded.
        alert( "Red has been clicked, but not the yellow area");
    }
});
```

Thus, you can write your code to filter out clicks on any number of descendent elements, without even knowing their classes/ids.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/os6rufs4/)**